# My variable is null even though i set it in a different thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety

The button is always set to "sady", and i dont know why. the button only displays sady if the BufferedReader, reader, is null, though it is set in the other thread, just like the writer that is also is set in the other thread. Does anyone know why that it isnt working? Here is the code, it is supposed to hook up to my server.
package catz.mycooldomain.octopoco.chatapp;

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {
    EditText edittext;
    TextView textview;
    Button button;
    Socket sock;
    static BufferedReader reader;
    PrintWriter writer;
    boolean threadnotsetup=true;
    boolean readerSetup=true;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setTitle("VerySimpleChatClient");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main,container,false);
        edittext=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        edittext.setText("hello world");
        textview=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textview);
        textview.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        button=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setText("send");
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                writer.println(edittext.getText());
                writer.flush();
            }
        });
        Thread thread=new Thread(new NetworkTest());
        thread.start();
        Thread thereader=new Thread(new ReaderThread());
        thereader.start();
        return v;


    }
    class NetworkTest implements Runnable{
            public void run() {
                while (threadnotsetup) {
                    try {
                        sock = new Socket("10.0.0.11", 5000);

                        InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
                        MainActivityFragment.reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);

                        writer = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
                        writer.println("Thomas has joined the room");

                        threadnotsetup=false;
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();

                    }

                }
            }
    }
    class ReaderThread implements Runnable{
    public void run() {
        if (!threadnotsetup) {
            button.setText(Boolean.toString(threadnotsetup));
            try {
                String text = "";
                if (MainActivityFragment.reader == null) {
                    button.setText("sady");
                } else {
                    button.setText("worksy");
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                button.setText(ex.toString());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you making sure that the other thread is running before you access the variable? It may be the case that the value is not set yet. You should make sure that no matter what, the other thread will run first.

You can make sure of this by adding a sleep statement. If you do not want to add a sleep or wait, then at least for debugging purposes you can check whether synchronization is an issue.

Comment: `threadnotsetup` is shared variable between two threads. You are not using synchronization or anything to check if value of this variable is a expected. And your code can't make sure that which thread would run first. Request you to read a few basic things about multi-threading.

Comment: You can't ever _fix_ a concurrency problem by adding `sleep()` calls.  You can make it _much_ less likely to happen, and in demos and other non-critical software that might be enough, but for mission-critical code, you need positive synchronization.